# Is it possibile to super-cast a List?

Tags: java, list, casting

This might sound a little bit trivial, but I'm really not able to find the crux of the matter.

```
List<Dog> dogs = getListOfDogs();
List<Cat> cats = getListOfCats();

feed(dogs);
feed(cats);

public void feed(List<Animal> animals) {
    // feed the animal:
    // depending on the type of animal, I might want to give it
    // different kind of food.
}

class Dog implements Animal { /**/ }
class Cat implements Animal { /**/ }
interface Animal { /**/ }
```

I'm in a context very similar to the one depicted above. 
Let's also suppose that `getListOfDogs` and `getListOfCats` are fixed, and there's no way to act on that side.

Of course, as put in that way, it's an illegal code: `feed` accepts only `List<Animal>` types, while I can only have `List<Cat>` and `List<Dog>`.

Since `feed` is a function that is almost identical for the two animals, with the exception of the kind of food (and I can manage it via `instanceof`), I would like to avoid copying it, just changing the signatures.

Is there any way to super-cast the two lists? Something like this (that is obviously incorrect): `feed((List<Animal>) getListOfDogs());`

Comment: `feed` should accept `List<? extends Animal>`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: In case you haven't seen it there is useful discussion around generics and collections here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* do what you've said you want, by declaring `feed` like this:

```
public void feed(List<? extends Animal> animals)
```

**However**, you may well not want to do that, because of your subsequent statement:

> Since `feed` is a function that is almost identical for the two animals, with the exception of the kind of food (and I can manage it via `instanceof`)...

Don't reach for `instanceof` lightly, it's usually the wrong tool. Instead, parameterize `feed`:

```
private void feed(List<? extends Animal> animals, Food food)
```

...and then

```
public void feed(List<Dog> animals) {
    this.feed(animals, this.dogFood);
}
```

and

```
public void feed(List<Cat> animals) {
    this.feed(animals, this.catFood);
}
```

...or similar.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is:

```
public void feed(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
```

This will accept a `List<Animal>`, or a `List<Dog>`, or a `List<Cat>`, or so on. You won't be able to add anything to `animals`, since it could be any type of list. If you access an item in `animals` you'll get back a reference of type `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't let you cast directly to `List<Animal>`, then you could cast to a `List` without the generic parameter and then to `List<Animal>`, but this is not a good approach.

This is not a good approach, because once you change the generic parameter you would be able to put cats into your list of dogs.

Instead, the feed function's parameter should look different

```
public void feed(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
    // feed the animal:
}
```

This way you will be able to get the animals out from the list as `Animal`s, but won't be able to put animals of the wrong type into the list.